# how to rectify "angular is not defined" error in app.js file in intel xdk

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, intel-xdk

Below is the code please specify the changes to be done.

I think the scripts are included in the right place i've also changed the scripts to include angularjs to various positions it still does'nt work

Please, help.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp" >
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ionic/css/ionic.min.css">
            <title></title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">        
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
            <style>

                    @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% ; zoom: 100% ; }          @viewport { width: 100vw ; min-zoom: 100% zoom: 100% ; }
                    @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }                   @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; min-zoom: 100% ; }

            </style>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-rc.0/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="ionic/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="ionic/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="cordova.js" id="xdkJScordova_"></script>
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>
            <!-- for your event code, see README and file comments for details -->
            <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
            <!-- for your init code, see README and file comments for details -->
            <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
            <!-- normalizes device and document ready events, see file for details -->
            <script type="application/javascript" src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="application/javascript" src="marginal/marginal-position.js"></script>
            <script type="application/javascript" src="ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
            <script type="application/javascript" src="js/index_init_services.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller="myCtrl">

            <div class="upage" id="mainpage">
                <div class="upage-outer">
                    <div class="upage-content ac0 content-area vertical-col left">
                        <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_1 row-height-1" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                            <div class="col uib_col_1 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                    <label class="item item-input widget uib_w_2 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0"><span class="input-label">emp id</span>
                                        <input type="text" ng-model="eid">
                                    </label>
                                    <label class="item item-input widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0"><span class="input-label">password</span>
                                        <input type="password" ng-model="pwd">
                                    </label><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="grid grid-pad urow uib_row_2 row-height-2" data-uib="layout/row" data-ver="0">
                            <div class="col uib_col_2 col-0_12-12" data-uib="layout/col" data-ver="0">
                                <div class="widget-container content-area vertical-col">
                                    <button class="button widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" onclick="check_credentials()">Login</button><span class="uib_shim"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="uib_shim"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <ion-header-bar class="bar inner-element uib_w_1 bar-positive bar-header" data-uib="ionic/header" data-ver="0">
                        <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col"></div>
                        <h1 class="title">header</h1>
                        <div class="buttons widget-container content-area horiz-area wrapping-col"></div>
                    </ion-header-bar>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you look in your browser console, it should give you the line number the error is occurring on.

Comment: load only one angular js file, you are loading it thrice with 3 different version..Instead of all this load `ionic.bundle.js` will probably solve your issue..